# Create Datetime Column from Integer Column - Hours and Minutes

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, type-conversion

I have a dataframe with a 4 digit int column:

```
df['time'].head(10)
0    1844
1    2151
2    1341
3    2252
4    2252
5    1216
6    2334
7    2247
8    2237
9    1651
Name: DepTime, dtype: int64
```

I have verified that max is 2400 and min is 1. I would like to convert this to a date time column with hours and minutes. How would I do that?

Comment: pass format with to_datetime

Comment: Could you please provide an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these are 4 digits, `timedelta` is more appropriate than `datetime`:

```
pd.to_timedelta(df['time']//100 * 60 + df['time'] % 100, unit='m')
```

Output:

```
0   18:44:00
1   21:51:00
2   13:41:00
3   22:52:00
4   22:52:00
5   12:16:00
6   23:34:00
7   22:47:00
8   22:37:00
9   16:51:00
Name: time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

If you have another column `date`, you may want to merge `date` and `time` to create a `datetime` column.

Comment: Timedelta is the only solution that works flawlessly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

```
pd.to_datetime(df.time.astype(str),format='%H%M').dt.strftime('%H:%M')
Out[324]: 
0    21:51
1    13:41
2    22:52
3    22:52
4    12:16
5    23:34
6    22:47
7    22:37
8    16:51
Name: col2, dtype: object
```

Comment: This is almost correct. Switch `col2` with `time` :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
df['conversion'] = (df['time'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format = '%H%M')).dt.strftime('%H:%M'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want output in string format of `HH:MM`, you just need to convert column to string and use `str.slice_replace` with `:` (**Note**: *I change your sample to include case of 3-digit integer*)

sample df:

```
     time
0    1844
1    2151
2    1341
3    2252
4    2252
5    216
6    2334
7    2247
8    2237
9    1651

s = df['time'].map('{0:04}'.format)
out = s.str.slice_replace(2,2,':')

Out[666]:
0    18:44
1    21:51
2    13:41
3    22:52
4    22:52
5    02:16
6    23:34
7    22:47
8    22:37
9    16:51
Name: time, dtype: object
```

---

Or split and concat with `:`

```
s = df['time'].map('{0:04}'.format)
out = s.str[:2] + ':' + s.str[2:]

Out[665]:
0    18:44
1    21:51
2    13:41
3    22:52
4    22:52
5    02:16
6    23:34
7    22:47
8    22:37
9    16:51
Name: time, dtype: object
```